# Get column and row name when click on cell in datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I use datatables (http://datatables.net/) for creating table with JSON and I have a code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
        "ajax": "objects.txt",
        "columns": [
            { "data": "name" },
            { "data": "position" },
            { "data": "office" },
            { "data": "extn" },
            { "data": "start_date" },
            { "data": "salary" }
        ]
    } );
} );
</script>
<div class="container">
<table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-responsitive" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>DAN</th>
                <th>Aktivnost</th>
                <th>Vreme</th>
                <th>Rashodi</th>
                <th>Prihodi</th>
                <th>Beleske</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>DAN</th>
                <th>Aktivnost</th>
                <th>Vreme</th>
                <th>Rashodi</th>
                <th>Prihodi</th>
                <th>Beleske</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
    </div>
```

How I can get name of row and name of column when I click on some cell ?
ALso how to get ID of row and ID of column when click on some cell in table?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think this will help you:

[Column Selector](http://datatables.net/reference/type/column-selector)

[Row Selector](http://datatables.net/reference/type/row-selector)

OR

You can try this type of code using JQuery:

```
    $('#example tbody').on( 'click', 'td', function () {
        alert('Data:'+$(this).html().trim());
        alert('Row:'+$(this).parent().find('td').html().trim());
        alert('Column:'+$('#example thead tr th').eq($(this).index()).html().trim());
    });
```

This is the fiddle for JQuery code: [**CLICK HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/JarvisStark/Lb4phom4/2/)

Comment: Thanks, that help me. Is there any other way here ?

Comment: You should get hold of the row data by `table.row(this).data()` instead of readying the HTML DOM